# QT Designer: Using .ui files for other components created with QT Designer

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qt-designer

I have created a bunch of widgets with QT designer.

What I would like to know is if these widgets can be used (drag and dropped) with other components I create with QT Designer, without having to export them and compile them as a custom widget, since it seems that the .ui file already contains most of that functionality that I would be exporting with the custom widget interface.

Is this possible, or am I thinking about how components created with the Qt Designer can work together wrong?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.  Doesn't work that way.  You need to do all the custom widget crap.

I don't usually bother though.  I just put what I've supclassed from in the designer and then use the "promotion" feature.

Comment: Promotion is the way to go unless you're distributing the custom widgets to other folks.

Comment: Shortly after posting I discovered promotion. This does what I need, thanks for the answers guys.